# Using python 3.5 on one script and 2.7 on another, can I use IPC (mmap) or sockets to read the value in one process as soon as the other updates it?

Tags: python, process, pyqt5, ipc

I'm wondering if this is possible. I am running a rasperry pi Model 3B on Raspbian Jessie. I have python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed. On python 3.5 I am running a GUI with PyQt5.

On python 2.7 I am running a script that uses a neopixel library.

I looked into Python's mmap as an IPC approach and while it seems promising, the examples basically had me use files through File IO, or file descriptors.

```py
# ProcessorScript.py
file1 = open("../distanceValue.txt", "wb")



file1.write(b"0")

file1.close()
```

```py
#receiverscript.py
file2 = open("../distanceValue.txt", "r+b")

mm = mmap.mmap(file2.fileno(), 0)

print(mm.readline())

print(mm)

mm.close()
```

The above approach allows me to manage a file as a buffer for communicating between scripts.

But I want to be able to communicate between scripts and have the GUI script read the value from the other script as soon as it is updated without having to do some kind of polling.
Is it possible to make this event-driven?

Comment: While in this case it's *almost* harmless, please avoid using images for your code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362

Comment: noted, thank you. In the future I'll use the formatting

Comment: @total-N00b No, you must use it now. Please edit your question.

Comment: Edited. Can someone help with my problem?

Comment: @total-N00b It seems to me that it is not possible to use signals for this case, why don't you use dbus?